# Django max date less than specific date

Tags: django, date, max

```
context['roomfiltersettime'] = RoomLog.objects.filter(update_date__lte = choosend)
```

choosend is a chosen date manualy

so, above returns all RoomLog objecs with update date < choosend

in my template I do as follows:

```
{% for rl in roomfiltersettime %}
    {% if rl.room.id = room.id %}
        {{ rl.update_date }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

so, above conditions roomfiltersettime context by room.id object.

I would like NOT to return all roomfiltersettime objects less than chooseend date by room.id but I would like to return MAX rl but less than choosend for each room.id

How can I do it in django ?  should I do it in view or in templates ?

Comment: `MAX rl but less than choosend for each room.id` is confusing, what is `room.id`? Where in the code do you get `each room.id`?

Comment: I have a model 'Room' and model 'RoomLog'. each RoomLog has FK to Room. So, I have multiple Room objects and each Room has multiple RoomLog objects. each RoomLog object has update_date attribute. I use 'choosend' to filter RoomLogs with update_date less or equal than choosend. Although, I do not know how to display latest one RoomLog object for each Room object only with an update_date less or equal choosend. At the moment I display all RoomLog objects for each Room object with an update date less or equal choosend.

Comment: think about it like Reporters and Article. each Reporter can have many Articles and each Article has an update_date attribute. I want to return one Article with the most recent update_date (less or equal to choosend) date. for each Reporter.